# How to prove this question related to multi-times composite relation $\mathcal{R}^{n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I found a question somewhat difficult, on *An Invitation to Discrete Mathematics*, by Matousek et al., which goes as below.
$\newcommand{\op}[2]{ \left\langle #1 ,\, #2 \right\rangle }$
$\newcommand{\rel}[1]{ \mathcal{#1} }$

---

**Question**:

For a relation $\rel{R}$ on a set $X$ we define the symbol $\rel{R}^n$ by induction:
$$\rel{R}^1 = \rel{R},\, \rel{R}^{n+1}=\rel{R} \circ \rel{R}^n$$

(a) Prove that if $X$ is finite and $\rel{R}$ is a relation on it, then there exist $r, s \in \mathbb{N}$, $r < s$, such that $\rel{R}^r = \rel{R}^s$.

(b) Find a relation $\rel{R}$ on a finite set such that $\rel{R}^n \neq \rel{R}^{n+1}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

(c) Show that if $X$ is infinite, the claim (a) need not hold (i.e. a relation $\rel{R}$ may exist such that all the relations $\rel{R}^n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, are distinct).

---

**My Attempt**:

I had some trouble to define a finite set rigorously. Later, I decided not to struggle with the definition of the finite set. Instead, I chose to use a concept, *Adjacency Matrix*, to solve the problem.

First, I start with observing some examples.
Let $\rel{R} = \left\{ \op{x}{y} \mid x < y \right\} \subseteq A \times A$, where the set $A = \left\{ 1,\, 2,\, 3,\, 4,\, 5 \right\}$, while $\op{x}{y}$ is an ordered pair: $\op{x}{y} = \left\{ \left\{ x \right\},\, \left\{ x,\,y \right\} \right\}$. Now it is possible to make a graphic presentation of the relation $\rel{R}$ on the set $A$ as followed:

[image: The graphic presentation of the relation R]

Furthurmore, the adjacency matrix of the relation $\rel{R}$ is:

\begin{align}
J_{\rel{R}^1} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Similarly, we can get the graphic presentation and the adjacency matrix of the composite relation $\rel{R}^{2} = \rel{R}\circ\rel{R}$.

[image: The graphic presentation of the relation R^2]

\begin{align}
J_{\rel{R}^2} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

And so forth, the adjacency matrix of the composite relation $\rel{R}^{3}$, $\rel{R}^{4}$ and $\rel{R}^{5}$ are:

\begin{align}
J_{\rel{R}^3} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
J_{\rel{R}^4} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
J_{\rel{R}^5} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

It's obvious that $\forall i \in \mathbb{N},\, i > 5 :\: J_{\rel{R}^i} = J_{\rel{R}^5} = 0$, i.e. $\forall i \in \mathbb{N},\, i > 5 :\: \rel{R}^i = \rel{R}^5 = \varnothing$.

Meanwhile, let $\rel{S} = \left\{ \op{x}{y} \mid x = y \right\} \subseteq A \times A$. We can get $\rel{S} = \left\{ \op{1}{1},\, \op{2}{2},\, \op{3}{3},\, \op{4}{4},\, \op{5}{5} \right\}$. it's obvious that $\forall i \in \mathbb{N} :\: J_{\rel{S}^i} = I \;\land\; \rel{S}^{i} = \rel{S}$.

After the observation of some special cases as listed above, I started to prove the first sub-question.

Suppose $A$ is a finite set with *n* elements.

$$ A = \left\{a_1,\,a_2,\,\ldots{},\,a_n\right\} $$

Suppose $\rel{R}$ is a relation on $A$. It can be completely described by an $n \times n$ matrix $M = \left(m_{ij}\right)$, $i,\,j \in \left[1, n\right] \cap \mathbb{N}$, where
\begin{align}
m_{ij} = \left\{ \begin{array}{c}
  1,\ \text{if}\ \op{a_i}{a_j} \in R \\
  0,\ \text{if}\ \op{a_i}{a_j} \notin R
\end{array} \right.
\end{align}

---

I've got so far, but I cannot figure it out how to prove any of three sub-questions at all. Could you please help me? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question a)**
For $X$ is finite, the set of relations on $X$ is also finite, as a relation is a an element of the powerset $\mathcal P(X \times X)$. Therefore $\mathcal R^r = \mathcal R^s$ for some $r \lt s$.

**Question b)**
Take $X = \{1,2\}$ and $\mathcal R = \{(1,2), (2,1)\}$.

**Question c)**
Take $X = \mathbb N$ and $\mathcal R = \{(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), \dots\}$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\op}[2]{\langle #1,\,#2 \rangle}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}
\newcommand{\ps}[2]{\mathcal{#1}{\left(#2\right)}}
x,\,y \in X
\implies \set{x},\,\set{x,\,y} \subseteq X
\implies \set{x},\,\set{x,\,y} \in \ps{P}{X}
\implies \set{\set{x},\,\set{x,\,y}} \subseteq \ps{P}{X}
\implies \set{\set{x},\,\set{x,\,y}} \in \ps{PP}{X}
\implies \set{\set{\set{x},\,\set{x,\,y}}} \subseteq \ps{PP}{X}$

Comment: $\newcommand{\op}[2]{\langle #1,\,#2 \rangle}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}
\newcommand{\ps}[2]{\mathcal{#1}{\left(#2\right)}}
\op{x}{y} \in X^2 \implies \set{\op{x}{y}} \subseteq X^2 \implies \set{\op{x}{y}} \in \ps{P}{X^2} \implies R \in \ps{P}{X^2}$

Comment: Yes, indeed. *A relation is an element of the powerset* $\mathcal{P}{\left(X^2\right)}$.

Comment: I don't know the logic behind from "a relation is an element of the poswerset $\mathcal{P}{(X^2)}$" to $R^r = R^s$, could you please share some details?

Comment: If the $\mathcal R^s$ were all different, then the set of relations on $X$ Oullins be infinite. A contradiction.